# Dropbox and Google Drive folders slow to open from SSD

Tags: windows-7, ssd

In Windows 7 Pro 64-bit Windows Explorer, under Favorites, I have a link to Dropbox and Google Drive.

When I click on these folders, it takes about 5 seconds to open.

I know this is a first world problem, but I find it interrupts my flow.

When I click on any other folder on the C drive, it takes about 0.5 seconds to open.

The C drive is a Samsung 840 EVO MZ-7TE120BW 120GB Internal Solid State Drive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe it's because these folders are related to internet. 
I think: these folders need to be refreshed when opened, it can take time to get the "file list".
Maybe it can affect the speed.